# xcode flag error in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.m

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am getting the following error in SA_`OAuthTwitterEngine.m` as shown the below image

[image]

I added the frameworks and the twitter files also still i am getting this error 
I am unable to find the solution where it is?

Please Guide me..

Comment: the errors where it shows i placed an image  @PawanSharma

Comment: what's your compiler? seems a parser issue

Comment: Apple LLVM Compiler3.0  @MrBonjour

Comment: i tried with Default Apple LLVM Compiler3.0 also but the same issues comes @MrBonjour

Comment: if i put the compiler as LLVM GCC 4.2 then it shows 1 error i.e, "cc1objplus: error: unrecognized command line option "-fno-objc-arc"    @MrBonjour

Comment: it seems it can't understand it's a category. Try to remove this category (ctr-x), do a clean project then compile it again (you will get error or warning). Then add it again. If it's not working, then it could be a header missing @end somewhere. By the way  LLVM Compiler3.0 should work fine

Comment: i did 3 times ... even same errors repeats .... @MrBonjour

Comment: Then check what you have inserted before the categorie.

Comment: i did not get you ... "what you have inserted before the categorie."  means?  @MrBonjour

Comment: what do you have before the "@interface SA_OAUTHTwitterEngine (private)"? this is what seems to confuse the parser.  By the way try to compile with"@interface SA_OAUTHTwitterEngine ()" instead